# Haskell to Javascript compilers?

Tags: haskell

I've recently came across [ghcjs](https://github.com/pedromartins/ghcjs) haskell-to-javascript compiler, but I am not sure how "ready" it is. It seems to have little activity over the last year.

Is there an equivalent to GWT in Haskell?

Also, more of a discussion question:do you think there will be a gwt haskell equivalent? Why or why not?

Comment: I just came across this when searching for ghcjs. There is a newer repo: https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs

Comment: See also [What is the most production-level Haskell to JavaScript compiler, to write code running in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272226/what-is-the-most-production-level-haskell-to-javascript-compiler-to-write-code)

Answer (score 9):

There are several such compilers which can be used right away.

- Fay (formerly at http://fay-lang.org/, now on https://github.com/faylang/fay) The most popular and the most developed Haskell -> JS compiler. AFAIU, it implements Haskell from scratch and compiles it to JavaScript. It doesn't implement many of GHC's features, especially language extensions.
- Haste (https://github.com/valderman/haste-compiler) It uses the backend of GHC to compile to javascript. As a result you can use it to compile extension containing code.

Comment: I have made a [very brief comparision of both](https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/archives/602-Running-Circle-Packing-in-the-Browser-using-Haste.html).

Answer (score 7):

[Ji](http://chrisdone.com/posts/2011-12-26-ji-haskell-web.html) seems relevant, although it doesn't do any Haskell-to-JS compilation; it lets a Haskell server control a browser connected to it via AJAX.

It seems like [UHC](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/UHC) supports [compiling to JavaScript](http://chrisdone.com/posts/2012-01-06-uhc-javascript.html) and has some [libraries along those lines](https://github.com/norm2782/uhc-jscript), but I don't know what UHC's compatibility with GHC extensions is like, or how mature the support is.

I'm not convinced compiling full Haskell to JavaScript is a productive route; the overhead of implementing the likes of lazy evaluation on top of a high-level language is likely to be significant, and all the [attempts so far](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Yhc/Javascript) (I haven't checked out UHC's generated code) seem to produce rather huge JavaScript (admittedly, HTTP compression mitigates this).

I don't think ghcjs is being actively developed, but it might be more stable than UHC's support. Yhc's support seems to be the furthest so far, but unfortunately Yhc is a dead project.

Comment: Wow, that is amazing! Ji, that is. It would be extremely wicked if there was a templating engine in there, and some kind of url routing. How in the world does it "control" the browser? I thought the only way was through AJAX!

Comment: @drozzy: Via AJAX, like I said :)

Comment: Oh, I just saw the little js file hidden in there! Haha, clever.

Comment: GHCJS is actively maintained at the moment.